# Firebase Authentication Phone Number

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Imagine that I bought a new Chip Sim Card.
Then I tried to register this phone number in some application, but I get an error: This credential is already associated with a different user account.

How can I unlink / delete the older phone provider to use it on the newest account?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this using an Rest Function on Google Cloud.
When I got the error 1705 (This credential...) I call my service and Then try again.

```
exports.removeUserPhone = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

const phoneNumber = req.query.phoneNumber || req.body.phoneNumber
console.log("Phone Number:", phoneNumber);

var ret = { 
    success : true,
    result  : ""
};

admin.auth().getUserByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
.then(userRecord => {
    console.log("Successfully fetched user data:", userRecord.toJSON());

    admin.auth().updateUser(userRecord.uid, {
        phoneNumber: null
    })
    .then(userRecord2 => {
        ret.result = "Successfully updated user."
        res.send(ret)
        // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
        console.log("Successfully updated user", userRecord2.toJSON());
    })
    .catch(error => {
        ret.success = false
        ret.result  = "Error updating user."
        res.send(ret)
        console.log("Error updating user:", error);
    });
 })
 .catch(error => {
    ret.success = false
    ret.result  = "Error fetching user data."
    res.send(ret)
    console.log("Error fetching user data:", error);
    });
});
```

Idk if it's the best way, but it's working perfectly.