# How to check if phone number is already registered in firebase authentication using android java

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

i am trying make a simple page using java. Where User enter there Phone number if user Phone Number is already Registered  in Firebase Authentication they Logged in . If number not registered it goes for registration

Comment: @Zoe: this user is asking about Firebase Authentication, while you linked a question about the Firebase Realtime Database. While both products are part of Firebase, they are completely separate and have very different APIs. I find it very hard to consider these two questions as exact duplicates.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50313857/is-it-possible-to-check-phone-number-is-already-registered-in-firebase-else-goto, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50259448/firebase-authentication-phone-number and possibly more from https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-authentication%5D%5Bandroid%5D+phone+number+registered